# is there a ruby one-line "return if x"?

Tags: ruby, syntax

have a ton of places I need to add

```
if this_flag
  return
end
```

can that be done on one line with ruby?

Comment: Why not test this out before asking? Use `irb` and play around with what you can and CAN do with Ruby :)

Comment: @DJTripleThread: Makes me want to create "Let me IRB that for you".

Comment: for haters like the above two, please note the excellent RANGE of answers supplied below, that highlight the power of ruby (instead of whining about the one obvious answer being obvious). That is the power of SO and that is why I will never apologize for asking an 'obvious' question.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

> is there a ruby one-line “`return if x`” ?

Yes:

```
return value if condition
```

I love Ruby :-)

Comment: i'm getting there too... just KNEW they'd have a shortcut!

Answer (score 9):

Some additions to Jörg W Mittag's good answer:

```
x && return
x and return
if x then return end
```

I do not actually recommend the first two forms: however, the above examples are all valid productions. I personally prefer to avoid `return` in general -- most grammar constructs in Ruby are usable expressions.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby always returns the last thing... Why not just structure your code differently?

```
def returner(test)    
  "success" if test   
end
```

Whatever you've done last will return. I love Ruby.

Comment: Yes, the method definition will return `nil`.   
However, calling the method will return different things... depending.
`returner(true)` => `"success"`
While `returner(false)` => `nil`

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that check for the expected class types
Example below. Method `check_class` will return true as soon as it finds the correct class.
Useful if you may need to expand the number of different class types for any reason.

```
def check_class(x)
  return true if is_string(x) 
  return true if is_integer(x)
  # etc etc for possible class types
  return false # Otherwise return false
end

def is_string(y)
  y.is_a? String
end

def is_integer(z)
  z.is_a? Integer
end


a = "string"
puts "#{check_class(a)}"
```