# Shorthand for "return x if x" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shorthand

One thing I love about Ruby is that you can express things in the shortest way possible.

I know that one can do, when assigning

```
x ||= a
# instead of
x = a unless x
# which is
x = x || a
```

Is there an analog form for `return`?

```
# instead of
return x if x
```

I'm trying to "say" `x` only once. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436034/is-there-a-ruby-one-line-return-if-x) asks about just returning (nothing), but I don't see how to do it when returning something other than void.

Comment: What is wrong with replacing `return x if x` with simply `x` ?

Comment: @Zabba It is not necessarily the last statement

Comment: Maybe my math skills have deteriorated, but isn't what you have already a one-liner?

Comment: Astute observation, @Jorg; I corrected it to "shorthand".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just about certain that there exists no shorthand for your second example—nor could one be written without modifying the Ruby syntax—since it's not a common enough idiom. Sorry, bro, but it looks like you're going to have to be verbose on this one. (Though, really, as far as verbosity goes, this one isn't all that bad.)

(Note, too, that the first example isn't quite right: `x ||= a` is equivalent to `x = x || a`, which can also be expressed as `x = a unless x`.)

Comment: You're right, I just corrected it. Since you're "just about certain", I'll wait a bit and admit this as the answer `unless` someone else has one. So `answer = yours; answer ||= new_answer`, or should I say `return new_answer if new_answer; yours;` ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can omit the return if it is the last statement in a block code.

example

```
irb(main):002:0> def b(c)
irb(main):003:1>   c if c
irb(main):004:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> b(4)
=> 4
irb(main):006:0> b(nil)
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> b(true)
=> true
irb(main):008:0> b(false) # TADA!!!
=> nil
```

Comment: I can sure omit `return` if it's my last statement, but my intention was to say `c` only once. And in my case, I want to cover not-last statements too!